# How to convert a string like ABCDEFG in AbCdEfG in sql

Tags: sql

I want o/p of select statement so that it will show alternate letters of given uppercase string in lowercase.

For example if input string is:

> ABCDEFG

then output should be:

> AbCdEfG

Comment: Why? And which DBMS are you using. sql server <> mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function containing a simple loop that performs upper/lower casing on your string.

For example in SQL Server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[AlternateCase]
(
    @input_string nvarchar(max)
)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @counter int
    declare @result nvarchar (max)

    set @counter = 0
    set @result  = ''

    while @counter <= LEN(@input_string)
        begin
            if  @counter % 2 = 0
                set @result = @result + lower(substring(@input_string, @counter, 1))
            else
                set @result = @result + upper(substring(@input_string, @counter, 1))

            set @counter = @counter + 1
        end
    return @result
end
```

Now you can use the new function in your select statements:

```
select [dbo].[AlternateCase]('ABCDEFG')
```

and this select will return:

> AbCdEfG